# isHardwareAccelerated() always returns false

Tags: android, hardware-acceleration

I am trying to turn on hardware acceleration for my  application
but I never seem to get a 'true' result from this function.
I tried all the methods in the Android Developers blog post about the
the  tag  android:hardwareAccelerated=true  to the application
and even called

```
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
```

[image]

Comment: you probably need to turn the hardware acceleration on in the activity's onCreate, before setting the content view

Comment: In activity also i used the code  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
in oncreate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always call `isHardwareAccelearted()` after the view is attached to the window. I am not sure about your case as I can't see where actually you are calling it.

Also, the support level of various operations across API levels are mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel#unsupported). I hope this helps.

You can also try this method to verify hardwareAcceleration.

```
public static boolean hasHardwareAcceleration(Activity activity) {
    // Has HW acceleration been enabled manually in the current window?
    Window window = activity.getWindow();
    if (window != null) {
      if ((window.getAttributes().flags
          & WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED) != 0) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    // Has HW acceleration been enabled in the manifest?
    try {
      ActivityInfo info = activity.getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(
          activity.getComponentName(), 0);
      if ((info.flags & ActivityInfo.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED) != 0) {
        return true;
      }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
      Log.e("Chrome", "getActivityInfo(self) should not fail");
    }

    return false;
  }
```

For checking for View try this.

```
 chat_wv.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Log.e("isHardwareAccelerated", ""+chat_wv.isHardwareAccelerated());
      }
    });
```

Comment: I am calling the  isHardwareAccelearted() after view attached to window only

Comment: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            chat_wv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }
        else {
            chat_wv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }

og.d(TAG, "initUI() chat_wv = ["+"is hard ware accelarate---------"+chat_wv.isHardwareAccelerated()+"]");

Comment: This doesn't attach the view to the window. Check in View.onSizeChanged(...) or getDecorView().isHardwareAccelerated()

Comment: hasHardwareAcceleration() method returns true for the activity. How can check for the view? mywebview.isHardwareAccelerated() returns false still

Comment: Try calling inside chat_wv.post();

Comment: can you explain in detail please

Comment: Thank you So much. 
It is retunning  true

Comment: @BharathiG Accept the answer if it worked for you. It will help other people